# Scroll wheel doesn't always scroll page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexslider

I've recently implemented flexslider for a full screen slideshow effect.

www.ianandtaylor.com

I had to implement some hackarounds to get vertical scrolling for flexslider slide content, however the scroll wheel doesn't appear to always work when I attempt to scroll. Touch and keyboard scrolling seem just fine, but the scroll wheel is very inconsistent. Sometimes, if I go into my inspection tool and flip some CSS rule on or off for the slide element, the scrolling starts working fine (not sure why).

*Ultimately, I just want to have a simple, easy scroll working on the Engagement Photos and Location & Event details slides.*

Any help here would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it, you want it to slide vertical when you scroll. 
That can give some complications with the gallery you have, so when you 
scroll it will either stop sliding when you reach the gallery or it will 
just continue and disable the scrolling through gallery.

Comment: Well that's kind of self evident at this point. It is important to note that other events like touch register just as they are expected to.

Comment: Sorry i can't help you with more :) - just trying to point out some  problems.
I wouldn't go for the trouble of making a function which will make it slide when you scroll, i don't think it's userfriendly in anyway because it changes the original function of the scroll.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I just have content on one side that needs to scroll. Not "slide when you scroll".